# Angular 2 Upload file to FTP server

Tags: angular, upload, ftp

I am quite new to this technology. I need to know how to upload a file to an FTP server using angular 2. 
Any code snippets? Any tutorial pages?
I have searched exhaustively, but I dont have a working, good example to try.
Thanks in advance. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Angular 2 doesn't offer a specific solution for uploading files.

But Angular is just JavaScript, so your question really is "how to upload files in JavaScript".

You have two main options:

- **Using the File API.** See the very clear [File API documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) (with plenty of code examples). This API is part of HTML5 and older browsers may not support it. In that case, you might have to use [one of these polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api).
- **Using a third-party library.** There are open-source libraries (e.g. http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and paying libraries (e.g. https://www.filestack.com/). A Google search will reveal more options.

Comment: tried dropzone, it doesnt work. I am not able to upload to a ftp server using javascript too. Please provide help with working code snippets :(

Comment: This answer does not solve the OP question. It only addresses how to select a file and (maybe) opening it, but does not address the FTP upload part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

direct FPT call is not supported JS, what you can do here

1. from (Javascript  or angular) to (C# or node or any backend) using file chunks
2. from the backend you can call the FTP server (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0d5b44/ftp-using-C-Sharp-net/)

In above link you can see example of C# to FTP server